# How do I separate objects using the mirror modifier in Blender 2.82?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I looked up the question already but they posts are from 6 years ago and the steps are outdated. The problem is that I added a mirror modifier to the shins and feet of my character. The question i how do I make the mirrored part an individual object. I have tried adding an empty axis but it didn't work the way I expected it to. When I select one, both are selected. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mheXx.png)

I put the bender file
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vzkE2NsZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the modifiers tab, and press *Apply*, on the *Mirror Modifier*. That will convert it to actual geometry.

Then, in *Edit Mode*, select one half of the object, and press <kbd>P</kbd>  > *Selection*. This will make it into a separate object.